# CALayer with different effects between iPhone / iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, calayer

This has me a bit confused. I have a universal app which has two different Storyboards for iPhone and iPad.  I'm using a small block of `CALayer` code to round the edges of a view and throw a shadow on it. Works perfectly on the iPhone.

```
[self configShadowLayer:_view
           cornerRadius:_view.frame.size.width / 2.0
          shadowOffsetX:0.0
          shadowOffsetY:3.0
           shadowRadius:2.0
                opacity:0.2];


-(void)configShadowLayer:(UIView *)shadowView
        cornerRadius:(float)cornerRadius
       shadowOffsetX:(float)shadowOffsetX
       shadowOffsetY:(float)shadowOffsetY
        shadowRadius:(float)shadowRadius
             opacity:(float)opacity {

    CALayer *shadowLayer = shadowView.layer;
    shadowLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
    shadowLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY);
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = opacity;
}
```

On the iPad, it gives me a diamond shape.  I have to change the corner radius from the half to a quarter and then it works.  But then of course the iPhone view goes from a circle to a rounded rect.

What am I missing?

[image: iPhone view]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `configShadowLayer:cornerRadius:shadowOffsetX:shadowOffsetY:shadowRadius:opacity:` after the layout of the view is done. When you call it only before the layout process the view's frame has probably the wrong sizes, and you will get a corner radius which is too large.

BTW: You should compute the radius depending to the bounds of the view, because the bounds represents the coordinate system inside of the view.

Comment: I actually tried using _view.bounds.size.width as well but had the same results.  I thought I had it I was calling it `viewWillAppear` but it looks like it was actually in `viewDidLoad`.  Yuck.   I'll try moving the call to later on in the process... and see what happens.

Comment: Excellent.  I knew it was something stupid like that.  Ugh... why didn't I check that sooner.  Never even occurred to me.  Thank you so much.